# Count the data table row with specific condition in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have table like this:

```
<p:dataTable var="result" rows="5" value="#{analysisResultTokoBean.dataResultAnalysis}"
        style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-top: 0px;" paginator="true"
        pageLinks="5" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
        widgetVar="widgetWorkOrderResultToko" rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
        paginatorPosition="bottom" emptyMessage="No record found"
        styleClass="no-dtbl-header" id="pma"
        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}">
        <p:columnGroup type="header">
            <p:column headerText="Toko" />
            <p:column headerText="Produk" />
            <p:column headerText="Kategori" />
            <p:column headerText="Grafik Produk" />
            <p:column headerText="Action" colspan="2"/>
        </p:columnGroup>

        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{result.storeName}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{result.productName}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{result.categoryProduct}" />
            <!--  
            <p:commandLink style="float:right; color:blue;" value="Kategori">
                <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Action Untuk Produk?" icon="ui-icon-alert"/>
            </p:commandLink> -->
        </p:column>
        <p:column style="text-align: center;">
            <p:commandLink oncomplete="PF('dlg-graphic-each-toko').show()"
                actionListener="#{analysisResultTokoBean.prepareGraphicEachToko(result)}">
                <p:graphicImage name="grafik.png" library="images" width="40px" height="40px"/>
            </p:commandLink>
        </p:column>
        <p:column style="text-align: center;">
            <p:commandLink rendered="#{result.categoryProduct == 'Fast Moving'}" oncomplete="PF('dlg-addstock').show()"
                actionListener="#{analysisResultTokoBean.prepareCraeteAddStockToko(result)}"
                update=":dialogForm:dialogAddStock">

                <p:graphicImage name="tambah-stok.png" library="images" width="55px" height="40px"/>
            </p:commandLink>
            <p:commandLink rendered="#{result.categoryProduct == 'Slow Moving'}" onclick="PF('dlg-elimination').show()"
                actionListener="#{analysisResultTokoBean.prepareCreateEliminationToko(result)}">

                <p:graphicImage name="eleminasi.png" library="images" width="40px" height="40px"/>
            </p:commandLink>
        </p:column>
        <p:column style="text-align: center;">
            <p:commandLink oncomplete="PF('dlg-event').show();" rendered="#{result.categoryProduct == 'Fast Moving'}"
                actionListener="#{analysisResultTokoBean.prepareCreateEventToko(result)}">
                <p:graphicImage name="event.png" library="images" width="110px" height="40px"/>
            </p:commandLink>
            <p:commandLink oncomplete="PF('dlg-promo').show();" rendered="#{result.categoryProduct == 'Slow Moving'}"
                actionListener="#{analysisResultTokoBean.prepareCraetePromoToko(result)}">
                <p:graphicImage name="promo-2.png" library="images" width="70px" height="40px"/>
            </p:commandLink>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

If you guys see that I'm using rendered to make a conditional things. There is fast moving and slow moving condition to show off the command link. My question is can I count the row if it was fast moving or slow moving. I want to keep the count value to make the bar chart show how many fast moving dan slow moving is.

Comment: Do you need something like [this - Row Grouping](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/rowGroup.xhtml)? Or like [this - SummaryRow](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/summaryRow.xhtml), maybe with these two totals?

Comment: and I don't see any chart...

Comment: I will try it. Thanks @WoAiNii

Comment: The chart will be showed in the other page @Kukeltje